# Store Variable Across all Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is probably a simple task, but I have not been able to find a good example of how to accomplish this.  In my asp application, I have a TextBox a user can update.  I am looking for a way to store this variable's value in a central location so that the TextBox's Text property is set to that variable for any user who accesses the page.  Also, this variable should persist until another user updates it.
Worst comes to worst, I can create a database table to store this value and pull it from there, but I imagined asp or IIS would have this functionality built in.

Comment: What you are looking for is referred to as "Application State".

Comment: What you're looking for here is a database.  That's the appropriate solution to this problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might be looking for is referred to as [`Application State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can use it as follows:

```
Application["Message"] = "Welcome to the Contoso site.";
```

You can even store objects, like a List for example:

```
Application["MyList"] = new List<string>();

List<string> myList = Application["MyList"] as List<string>;
myList.Add("Test");
```

**Concurrency Concerns**

As *Vlad Bezden* added, it is important to synchronize the Application collection in the event that multiple threads attempt to modify it simultaneously. This is done by first locking and then unlocking the collection as follows:

```
Application.Lock();
//Do any code that modifies or retrieves a value from the collection here
Application['MyMessage'] = "MyMessage";
MyClass myObject = Application['MyObject'] as MyClass;
Application.UnLock(); //Make sure you unlock it, or you will be in for a world of hurt.
```

> Application state is free-threaded, which means that
>   application state data can be accessed simultaneously by many threads.
>   Therefore, it is important to ensure that when you update application
>   state data, you do so in a thread-safe manner by including built-in
>   synchronization support. You can use the Lock and UnLock methods to
>   ensure data integrity by locking the data for writing by only one
>   source at a time. You can also reduce the likelihood of concurrency
>   problems by initializing application state values in the
>   Application_Start method in the Global.asax file.

Read more about [concurrency concerns here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

**Scalability Concerns**

As *John Saunders* and *Servy* pointed out in comments, if your application needs to consider scaling, as in a web farm/cloud scenario where multiple web servers are running your application together, then it is advisable that you consider employing a database solution for maintaining your persistent data. You can then scale your database needs independently of your web server, and it can handle some of the concurrency concerns as well. You might still wish to use Application State in this scenario, though, to cache data that is not updated often.

Comment: Hmmm. This won't work quite so well on a web farm.

Comment: @JohnSaunders He didn't seem to indicate that he was running a web farm =]

Comment: @crush The issue is that it's often hard to predict how an application will scale.  It may not be *now*, but it may very well be in a few years.

Comment: @Servy Without knowing more about what he aims to accomplish, a database could be absolute overkill as well. There are plenty of reasons to cache things in Application State, and not continuously requery a database on every page request.

Comment: @crush Caching, who said this was caching?  Caching *is* an appropriate use of app state.  The idea is that it's not the primary storage location for that data, it's just a copy to avoid the expense of fetching or computing it again.  If you have a farm it's appropriate for each server within it to have different copies of the caches, so long as you ensure they're kept in sync.  The OP hasn't indicated that what he's doing is caching info, in fact he indicated the opposite, that this would be the primary storage location for this data.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps you are right, and I read the OPs question a bit too carelessly. Still, if he is not writing to the database often, he will still want to cache the value in Application state to minimize reads. It would be nice to know more about what he aims to accomplish.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I totally expected the downvotes for this question, lol.  I was looking for a way to manage this without writing to a database table and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one web server you can use Application state, however Application state will not work on web farm.  If your application is going to run on web farm and your state needs to be shared between multiple web servers you should go with centralize storage (DB).

In case if Application State works for you, make sure you don't have race condition you need to Lock and Unlock Applicaion object before you make changes to it

```
Application.Lock();
Application["myMessage"] = newValue;
Application.UnLock();
```

Comment: Good additions to my answer below. If the value that he is persisting across requests/sessions were going to change a minority of the time, wouldn't it be beneficial to store it in a database for persistence/failover AND cache it locally in the application state to minimize fetches?

Comment: I didn't think about accounting for a race condition, so thank you for building on this.